# catching a deadlock in a simple odd-even sending

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

I'm trying to solve a simple problem with MPI, my implementation is MPICH2 and my code is in fortran. I have used the blocking send and receive, the idea is so simple but when I run it it crashes!!! I have absolutely no idea what is wrong? can anyone make quote on this issue please? there is a piece of the code:

```
integer, parameter :: IM=100, JM=100
REAL, ALLOCATABLE  :: T(:,:), TF(:,:)

CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,RNK,IERR)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,SIZ,IERR)

prv = rnk-1
nxt = rnk+1
LIM = INT(IM/SIZ)

IF (rnk==0) THEN
    ALLOCATE(TF(IM,JM))
    prv = MPI_PROC_NULL
ELSEIF(rnk==siz-1) THEN
    NXT = MPI_PROC_NULL
    LIM = LIM+MOD(IM,SIZ)
END IF

IF (MOD(RNK,2)==0) THEN
    CALL MPI_SEND(T(2,:),JM+2,MPI_REAL,PRV,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
    CALL MPI_RECV(T(1,:),JM+2,MPI_REAL,PRV,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,STAT,IERR)
ELSE
    CALL MPI_RECV(T(LIM+2,:),JM+2,MPI_REAL,NXT,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,STAT,IERR)
    CALL MPI_SEND(T(LIM+1,:),JM+2,MPI_REAL,NXT,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
END IF
```

as I understood even processes are not receiving anything while the odd ones finish sending successfully, in some cases when I added some print to observe what is going on I saw that the variable NXT is changing during the sending procedure!!! for example all the odd process was sending message to process 0 not their next one!

Comment: When providing code, please make sure it's formatted as such. Indent your code lines by four blanks. You also get formatting information on the right hand side of the 'ask question' page.

Answer (score 1):

The array T is not allocated so reading or writing from it is an error.

Comment: Sry that's part of a big program and I just paste some parts, I have already allocated the T with this line after the first if condition:
ALLOCATE(T(LIM+2,JM+2))

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the whole program, but some observation on what I can see:

1) make sure that rnk, size, and prv are integers.  Likely, prv is real (by default 
  typing rules) and you are sending a real to an integer, so tags don't match, hence deadlock.

2) I'd use sendrcv rather than send / recv ; recv / send code section. Two sendrecv's are cleaner ( 2 lines of code vs. 7), guaranteed not to deadlock, and is faster when you have bi-directional links (almost always true.)